# bash: config.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash

Whenever I open my terminal, it displays

bash: config.sh: No such file or directory

followed by the command prompt in the next line. My .bashrc file contains:

source config.sh

I mainly use Ubuntu for Root and Pythia et al, which seem to be working alright, but could someone tell me the possible reason for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find `whereis` the script  `config.sh`. 
Usually you can take it as *heritage* from some older *Phd* or *postdoc*.

Pay attention to the Environment variable of Root too (you can have problem later when you execute compiled macro).

To check if you just have it, try:

- `locate config.sh`
- `whereis config.sh`
- `find . -name "config.h"`

and so on...

Put the `~/` if it is in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `source config.sh` line from the `.bashrc` file.

And then source it.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

It will never happens again.

Comment: That will solve the problem of the error being displayed when you login - but the reason for the error is that Ubuntu cannot find this file within your $PATH.