# bash: /home/trotteville/root/bin/thisroot.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I know there are some similar questions in here, but I want to know how did this occur. The Terminal started displaying this after I deleted a folder named root in my home directory, but I assumed that I was only deleting something unnecessary(also I was not asked for authentication). How can I go back to the way everything was before :( ?

Also what will I be missing if I remove thisroot.sh from .bashrc ? following the solution in

[bash: config.sh: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473257/bash-config-sh-no-such-file-or-directory)

`~/.bashrc`'s content:

```bsh
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
source /home/trotteville/root/bin/thisroot.sh
```

Comment: Possibly your ~/bashrc refers to the missing file? take a look there

Comment: yes,  but as i am a newbie, I have no idea what was stored in the folder "root" {actually i had installed "root"(a statistical software) and i thought i was just removing files related to that}. but whatever the reason behind my problem, presently all I can think of is getting things back to normal

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the contents of your .bashrc file (you can either open it using a text editor or using the command `cat ~/.bashrc`)

Comment: yeah just pasted it, how do i modify this awful bold fonts? tried posting screenshots but wasn't allowed more than two as I don't have necessary ratings

Comment: I've done that for you, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
source /home/trotteville/root/bin/thisroot.sh
```

which tries to source `/home/trotteville/root/bin/thisroot.sh`, which doesn't exist.

The fix is simply to remove the line.

Comment: thanks  it works :) just one more query though,by removing that line will I be missing out on anything? or was the file thisroot.sh in /home/trotteville/ . . . . there for some functions which can't be performed anymore because of the deletion of the said "root" folder  in /home/trotteville ?

Comment: @ParthaBasumallick That I have no idea about, but since the file doesn't exist you're not missing out anything you weren't before ;)